# C# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start Cmd Jarsigner

Tags: c#, cmd, desktop-application, jarsigner

I want to run specific code with C# windows application on cmd(command prompt) for sign jar file.
 I used this code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"cmd", @"/K ""c:\program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\jarsigner.exe"" -keystore filepath.p12 filepath.jar ""alias_name""");
```

I encountered this error while I executing this code

Error:

```
'c:\program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Could not reproduce: i used `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"cmd", @"/K ""c:\program Files\winrar\winrar.exe"" t c:\test.rar");` and it worked as expected...

Comment: This code works.But my jarsigner.exe command dont work.If I write directly to cmd ,code works and ask for password for jar signature.
But I encountered this error while executing from Visual Studio

Comment: Any reason not to have `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\jarsigner.exe", @"-keystore filepath.p12 filepath.jar ""alias_name""");`?

Comment: It works.Why other command didn't work? System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"cmd", @"/K ""c:...");

Comment: Not sure, but apparently `cmd` doesn't manage to perfectly dispatch its parameters to the command included after the `/K` option. Luckily, bypassing the cmd intermediate and using the "Starts a process by specifying the name of an application and a set of command-line arguments" feature of Process.Start removes the disturbance of the "3rd-party". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments above, i understand this solves the issue:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\jarsigner.exe",
    @"-keystore filepath.p12 filepath.jar ""alias_name""");
```

Happy signing. ;-)

Comment: After executing this code jarsigner ask for password. If I write password, cmd screen disappears.I searched some site for this.It says put "/K" keyword .How can I use /K with this code?

Comment: The "/K" option is for a "cmd" process, not specifically related to jarsigner. But if you really want to use `cmd` you could write the `"c:\program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\jarsigner.exe" -keystore filepath.p12 filepath.jar "alias_name"` into a batch file (say, "signfile.bat"), and execute `Process.Start("cmd", "/K signfile.bat")`... HTH.

Comment: If you want to stop the jarsigner asking for a password you need to include the _storepass_ switch as per below.

    `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\jarsigner.exe",
        @"-keystore filepath.p12 -storepass TheStorePassword filepath.jar ""alias_name""");`

HTH :)